# Find repeated elements and it's count from multiple Flux's

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two flux which contains fruit names like below. I want out put with fruit name and it's count.

for eg:

```
Flux<String> flux1 = Flux.just("apple", "orang", "banana", "mangoes", "mangoes");
Flux<String> flux2 = Flux.just("pears", "limes", "banana", "plums", "apple");
```

expected output : apple -2, orang-1,banana-2,mangoes-2,pears-1,limes-1, etc..

is it better way to generate output in `Flux<Map>`? or any other best solution?

Comment: Your description doesn't match your expected output. You say you just want all *common* fruit names output, but then you include "orang", "pears" and "limes" in your expected output - none of which are common to both sets.

Comment: Why not use Java8 streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Map` is a single item you can generate a `Mono<Map<String, Long>>` as follows:

```java
Mono<Map<String, Long>> result = Flux.merge(flux1, flux2)
    .groupBy(it -> it)
    .flatMap(group -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(group.key()), group.count()))
    .collectMap(Tuple2::getT1, Tuple2::getT2);
```

Alternatively, you can also get a `Flux<Tuple2<String, Long>>` as follows:

```java
Flux<Tuple2<String, Long>> result = Flux.merge(flux1, flux2)
    .groupBy(it -> it)
    .flatMap(group -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(group.key()), group.count()));
```